# req.user and Is Authenticated always false

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, passport.js

I am using react with express.js  (inside router/user.js)

```
router.get("/", function (req, res) {
  console.log("this is u" , req.user)
   console.log(req.isAuthenticated());
  if (req.user) {
     res.json({ user: req.user })
  } else {
    res.json({ user: 'does not exsist' })
}
});
```

Here the console.log show the value against them as always undefined

```
console.log("this is u" , req.user)
       console.log(req.isAuthenticated());
```

The above code always console.log false, Now I went through the other examples where they mentioned the problem can be due to the way you put things in server.js(or app.js) and hence I checked and think that my problem is not because of that reason, Anyway this is how I am adding stuff

```
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat', // -> used to encode and decode the session, the seceret we used will be used to encode to decode
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

//Session



passport.use(new LocalStrategy(user.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(user.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(user.deserializeUser());
```

Here is my complete proper repository if someone wants to view: https://github.com/irohitb/litifier-

Now, Can anyone please guide me about fixing this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the login process is not being executed.
This results into cookie not being sent, which results into cookie not being read in the next request, which results into `req.isAuthenticated()` returning `false`

From the [passport.js docs](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/authenticate/),

> Note that when using a custom callback, it becomes the application's
>   responsibility to establish a session (by calling req.login()) and
>   send a response.

**Solution:**

As this looks like your signup page, I dont think you need to do `passport.authenticate` here. That is for login. Remove that.

After you register the new user, do the following:

```
req.logIn(user, function (err) {
     if (err) {
         return next(err);
     }
     return res.json(user) // send whatever you want or redirect
});
```

Comment: Hey @Dushyant, are you referring to post request here?

Comment: Yes, post at `"/"`. Also, the statement doesn't look to be valid
https://github.com/irohitb/litifier-/blob/master/server/routes/user.js#L42

Comment: Tried that, it says req#login requires a callback function

Comment: yes, provide a callback to `req.login(user)` ofcourse

Comment: That fixed it. 
Curious though, how did you find this statement invalid? `assport.authenticate("local"),function(req, res){` It is authenticating the user when it registers on to the platform?

Comment: Because the function after that is supposed to be a callback, which should be passed as an argument along with `"local"`. Technically, it is valid statement, but you are creating an anonymous function thats never getting executed. And as there was nothing in `req.user`, `passport.authenticate` was giving out false, so there was no login :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding  {credentials: 'include'} in the route

Example

```
get('/test', {credentials: 'include'})
```